# ReSwiftRecorder Add Action with property

Tags: swift

Recently I have used ReSwift API, And I want to add ReSwiftRecorder too!
The sample of [ReSwiftRecorder in Github](https://github.com/ReSwift/ReSwift-Recorder) is very simple app

I need to to something more complicated. I have an object which get data from server and I need to It reloads its data when app is not connected to net. Here is my code:

AppState:

```
struct AppState: StateType {
    var menus: Result<[Menu]>?
}
```

MenuReducer:

```
func menusReducer(state: Result<[Menu]>?, action: Action) -> Result<[Menu]>? {
    switch action {
    case let action as SetMenusAction:
        return action.menus
    default:
        return state
    }
}
```

AppReducer:

```
struct AppReducer: Reducer {

    func handleAction(action: Action, state: AppState?) -> AppState {
        return AppState(
            menus: menusReducer(state: state?.menus, action: action),
        )
    }
}
```

MenuActions:

```
struct SetMenus: Action {
    let menus: Result<[Menu]>
}
```

I know I need to change MenuAction to Something like this:

```
let SetMenusActionTypeMap: TypeMap = [SetMenusAction.type: SetMenusAction.self]

struct SetMenusAction: StandardActionConvertible {

    static let type = "SET_MENU_ACTION"
    let menus: Result<[Menu]>

    init() {}
    init(_ standardAction: StandardAction) {}

    func toStandardAction() -> StandardAction {
        return StandardAction(type: SetMenusAction.type, payload: [:], isTypedAction: true)
    }

}
```

but I got error on init functions

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

when I set a initializer code the error disappear but app does not restore saved data! How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to add serialization/deserialization code. The `menus` property needs to be set. Also, you will want to serialize that property as `payload`:

```
let SetMenusActionTypeMap: TypeMap = [SetMenusAction.type: SetMenusAction.self]

struct SetMenusAction: StandardActionConvertible {

    static let type = "SET_MENU_ACTION"
    let menus: Result<[Menu]>

    init() {
        self.menus = // however you initialize that
    }
    init(_ standardAction: StandardAction) {
        let maybeMenus = standardAction.payload["menus"] as? [Menu]?
        self.menus = // create Result from Optional<[Menu]>
    }

    func toStandardAction() -> StandardAction {
        let maybeMenus = self.menus.asOptional // Cannot serialize Result itself
        return StandardAction(type: SetMenusAction.type, payload: ["menus" : maybeMenus], isTypedAction: true)
    }

}
```

So problems I see here: JSON serialization depends on Dictionary representation of your payload data, i.e. the properties of your object. Can Result be serialized directly? I guess not, so you need to convert it, probably easiest to nil.

All in all, the payload is the key you missed and now you have to figure out how to use it with the data you have at hand. Also, it makes me a bit suspicious that the Result type itself is part of the AppState. I expected it to be reduced away or handled before dispatching an action, like `SettingMenusFailedAction` instead of `ChangeMenusAction(result:)` or similar. Just as a sidenote: actions should be more than typed property setters.

Comment: Thanks your answer is perfectly true.